# Item always selected in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a JTable where the included items are provided with radio buttons in order to enable users to select any of these once at a time. In order to show always the first item selected when the JTable is initialised (or when the item previously selected has been deleted) what method should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You should see [the JTable Javadoc](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) and particularly at :

```
getCellRect(int row, int column, boolean includeSpacing)
```

and

```
scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle aRect)
```

Something like

```
table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(table.getSelectedRows()[0], 0, true));
```

should suit you.